# GULO only for mammals?

Tags: genetics, mammals

I am not a biology student, but just want to know if GULO gene are present only in mammals or all species possess it ?

And is GULO gene active in human fetus?

Comment: On [Genecards](https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=GULOP#expression) it is mentioned that the GULO pseudo gene being expressed in humans in many major tissues. In that case the gene might be active although not encoding for a functional enzyme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GULO encodes [L-gulonolactone oxidase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-gulonolactone_oxidase) which catalyses a step in the biosynthetic pathway to ascorbic acid (vitamin C).

I did a BLAST search at NCBI using the mouse GULO protein as probe, excluding mammals, and I saw highly significant hits in reptiles, birds, sea urchins, fungi and bacteria. I conclude that this enzyme, (or very close relatives) is ubiquitous.

Humans (and other primates; also guinea pigs and the Dalmatian coach hound) have a defective GULO gene and so require dietary ascorbate.

Since the gene is non-functional in humans it isn't expressed in the foetus.

Comment: Wrong in regard to "Since the gene is non-functional in humans it isn't expressed in the foetus." See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

De Tullio writes

> We know from other studies that pseudogenes are not inert, but can have a significant role in epigenetic control of gene expression (Poliseno et al. 2010). Could this also apply to the human gulonolactone oxidase pseudogene? Time (and much research) will tell.
>
> De Tullio, M. C. (2010) The Mystery of Vitamin C. Nature Education 3(9):48
>
> https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/the-mystery-of-vitamin-c-14167861/

On [Genecards](https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=GULOP#expression) it is mentioned that the GULO pseudo gene being expressed in humans in many major tissues. In those cases the gene might have an epigenetic role.

Comment: This is just another example of Stack Exchange not working. I wrote the same thing as in this answer in a deleted answer. It was not reopened.